# Why does my Java program ignore my List in another html?

Tags: java, html, list, button, mapping

So my problem is that my List, to which I am adding a new record provided by the user, is ignored by my program when called upon.

This is the first html. The user provides me with their income, type of contract and their age:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String initialData(@RequestParam() double incomeParameter,
                              @RequestParam() String contractParameter,
                              @RequestParam() int ageParameter
    ) {
        if (!contractParameter.equals("Contract work") &&
                !contractParameter.equals("Contract of mandate") &&
                !contractParameter.equals("Contract of employment")) {
            return "firsterror";
        } else {
            User newUser = new User();
            newUser.setIncome(incomeParameter);
            newUser.setTypeOfContract(contractParameter);
            newUser.setAge(ageParameter);
            service.getUsersListCommon().add(newUser);

            return "secondpage";
        }
    }
```

Unless the *contractParameter* is one of the three mentioned in the code, he gets the first error. This works fine.

Then, I am trying to create a List to store the data provided by the user (income, contract, age). This is being done, because I will need this data for my method to work in the next page.

The List in which I am storing that initial data is located in the Service class and looks like this (not sure if the setter is even relevant, I am not using it anywhere):

```
List<User> usersListCommon = new ArrayList<User>();

    public List<User> getUsersListCommon() {
        return usersListCommon;
    }

    public void setUsersListCommon(List<User> usersListCommon) {
        this.usersListCommon = usersListCommon;
    }
```

It is @Autowired into my Controller class as *service*, hence you see *service.getUsersListCommon()*.

Then the user pushes *Submit* button and they are directed to another HTML in which below should happen:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/secondpage", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String detailedData(@RequestParam() int amountParameter,
                               @RequestParam() int timeParameter
    ) {
        User finalUser = new User();
        for (int i = 0; i < service.getUsersListCommon().size(); i++) {
            finalUser.setIncome(service.getUsersListCommon().get(i).getIncome());
            finalUser.setTypeOfContract(service.getUsersListCommon().get(i).getTypeOfContract());
            finalUser.setAge(service.getUsersListCommon().get(i).getAge());
        }
        if (finalUser.getAge() < 18) {
            return "tooyoung";
        } else if (finalUser.getIncome() < 2000) {
            return "toopoor";
        } else if (amountParameter > 10000) {
            return "toomuch";
        } else if (timeParameter > 35) {
            return "toolong";
        } else if (finalUser.getIncome() >= 2000 &&
                finalUser.getTypeOfContract().equals("Contract work") &&
                finalUser.getAge() <= 50 &&
                amountParameter <= 10000 &&
                amountParameter > 0 &&
                timeParameter <= 35) {
            return "granted";
        } else if (finalUser.getIncome() >= 2000 &&
                finalUser.getTypeOfContract().equals("Contract mandate") &&
                finalUser.getAge() <= 50 &&
                amountParameter <= 10000 &&
                amountParameter > 0 &&
                timeParameter <= 35) {
            return "granted";
        } else if (finalUser.getIncome() >= 2000 &&
                finalUser.getTypeOfContract().equals("Contract of employment") &&
                finalUser.getAge() <= 50 &&
                amountParameter <= 10000 &&
                amountParameter > 0 &&
                timeParameter <= 35) {
            return "granted";
        } else {
            return "requirementsnotmet";
        }
    }
```

Now, here the user is supposed to give me two more types of information - the amount of money they want as a loan and the desired length of time of the loan.

Don't mind the conditions being all the same for every type of contract, I didn't bother with it so far, due to it being a cosmetic thing at the moment.

**My main problem is that when the user provides this additional data and presses *Submit*... There is this error:**
*There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required double parameter 'incomeParameter' is not present*

So my program doesn't acknowledge that the previous data was provided and stored in the List which I am calling upon at the beginning of the second mapping method.

---

Also, not sure if relevant, but the first page of my program looks like this in the browser:
**http://localhost:8082/hello**

But when pushing the button in my html:

```
<body>
<form method="post">
<div id="header">Welcome to a swift creditworthiness' check.</div>
<div class="subheader">Please, provide all the required data below and push the button below to see the result.</div>
<input type="text" name="incomeParameter" placeholder="Your monthly income">
<input type="text" name="contractParameter" placeholder="Kind of contract">
<input type="text" name="ageParameter" placeholder="Your age">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
<div class="questions">In case of any questions, please proceed here:</div>
</body>
```

... it does redirect me to the next page:

```
<body>
<form method="post">
<div id="header">Please, provide additional required data below:</div>
<input type="text" name="amountParameter" placeholder="Desired amount of the loan">
<input type="text" name="timeParameter" placeholder="Desired time of the loan">
<input type="submit" value="Calculate">
</form>
</body>
```

But instead of looking like this: **http://localhost:8082/secondpage**, it still is **http://localhost:8082/hello**.

I think this is rather a long post, so thank you for dedicating the time to listen to my problems. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your "form" tags I can't see the "action" attribute.

Without "action", when you submit a form, the next web call is itself.

So, if you are in hello page and you press submit, you go (again) to hello page.

Comment: I thought that <form method="post"> is enough. :( Any idea what should I write as an "action"?
Example: <form method="post" action="?"> - what should I put there? The address to which it should go? Like "/secondpage"?

Comment: Your solution does resolve one of my issues (adding action="/secondpage" to the <form>), like now the localhost:8082 does show me /secondpage after hitting a button (so thanks for that :)), but now I have another issue as I am getting an error saying: "Required int parameter 'amountParameter' is not present"... I mean, I know it's not present because it supposed to be added right now? But before this can be done, I am getting this error already.

Comment: Ok for the first problema solved but now I need more details:

1) What are the html pages and their actions?

2) What are the @RequestMapping pages and their urls?

3) What is the "chain" of urls and actions that you want?

Comment: So basically the only two htmls that "do" anything are the ones shown above in the initial message. HTMLS "tooyoung", "toopoor", "toolong", "toomuch", "granted" and "requirementsnotmet" are just text messages. They don't do anything as for now.
The only two @RequestMappings with POST method are the ones shown above, other HTMLS all have only a GET mapping 
(e.g. @RequestMapping(value = "/tooyoungo", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String tooYoung() {
        return "tooyoung";
    }).

Comment: The idea is that the user starts at "/hello", provides incomeParameter, contractParameter and ageParameter, pushes submit and is directed to "/secondpage" in which he, in the same manner, provides amountParameter and timeParameter and pushes submit. At this moment my program should calculate the possible loan the user can get by taking incomeParameter, contractParameter and ageParameter that were stored in a List before moving to "/secondpage" and amountParameter and timeParameter that were just provided.

Comment: But instead of doing that, right now my program says that "Required int parameter 'amountParameter' is not present"... Just after I pushed Submit at the "/hello" page. I didn't even have the chance to provide the amountParemeter. This happened after I added action="/secondpage" to the form in html of "/hello". Before I added it, my program allowed me to provide amountParameter and timeParameter in the "/secondpage", but after pushing submit, it claimed that ageParameter is non-existent... So the List I created at the level of "/hello" is empty.

Comment: So, I suppose, that SOMEHOW that option action="secondpage" compels the program to give me.... the "final" (?) version of the page? It's just that I am getting the message that didn't provide amountParameter before I even had the chance to do it as if the program tried to run the method that is supposed to run after I push Submit on that "secondpage".

Comment: Parameters defined with @RequestParam are mandatory by default.
Maybe you can try with RequestParam(required = false) to have a chance to input amountParameter "later", but I think it's better to revise the flow:
a) user calls firstHtml, enters 3 params, submits the form and the action on firstHtml calls /hello
b) /hello "saves" data and "moves" the user to secondHtml
c) on secondHtml user enters 2 params, submits the form and the action on secondHtml calls /secondpage
d) /secondpage "saves" new data and "moves" the user to <other page>
What do you think about it?

Comment: I tried setting @RequestParam required = false, but, in the end (I had to change all variables to Longs, because the program "can't assign null value to a primitive type) it turns out the program refuses to acknowledge any user's input. Everything is a "null" to him, regardless of the variable type. Setting required = false gave me the final page where everything is a null. :(

Comment: Sorry for being kind of a pest about it, but could you check if I get it right?
User is calling hello.html (it has the <form> with action="hello"), submits the form, and the method assigned to value="/hello", saves the data and returns "secondpage". Then the secondpage.html also has the <form> with action="secondpage", has a method with value="/secondpage", but returns "otherpage"? Do I get it right?
I think that if I do not tell my hello.html to have the action="secondpage", then it will not change and thus the mapping for "/secondpage" won't function. 
Or am I missing something here? :(

Comment: Ok, I don't know how you did this, but it somewhat functions right now. I mean, my code does not recognise any factors that should make it e.g. tell the user they are too young (when under 18 years old), BUT it accepts the input on the hello.html and secondpage.html AND returns the final page, so it's already a huge leap. Huge thanks!

Comment: Ok, so far, it's like 99% of my code is the way I wanted it do. There is but a simple thing not related to the issue. All in all, thanks to you my code is functional. :D You saved my hopes and dreams.